# Why do I have so big delay while reading data from arduino?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

I try to read data from serial monitor using python and pyserial(I'm making a game that can be managed with arduino joystick). The problem is that I have a delay reading x and y **3 seconds**! What is causing so big delay and how can I reduce it?

Arduino code:

```
#define pinX    A2
#define pinY    A1
#define swPin    2 
#define ledPin  13

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(4800);
  
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinX, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinY, INPUT);
  
  pinMode(swPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(swPin, HIGH);
}
 
void loop() {
  boolean ledState = digitalRead(swPin); 
  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);        

  int X = analogRead(pinX);             
  int Y = analogRead(pinY);            

  Serial.println(X);              
  Serial.println(Y);
}
```

Python code:

```
import serial
from graphics import *
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import pygame
import math
ser=serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate=4800, timeout=10)
FPS = 10000000000
W = 1000
H = 500
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 70, 225)
dx = 0
dy = 0
V = 3
pygame.init()
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = W // 2
y = H // 2
rotatex = 0
r = 50
running = True
while running:
    ser.flush()
    xr = int(ser.readline().decode('ascii').strip())
    yr = int(ser.readline().decode('ascii').strip())
    print(xr)
    print(yr)
    sc.fill(WHITE)
    car = pygame.image.load('car.png')
    track1 = pygame.image.load('track.png')
    car_rect = car.get_rect(center=(x, y))
    track1_rect = track1.get_rect(center=(500, 250))
    car = pygame.transform.rotate(car, rotatex)
    sc.blit(track1, track1_rect)
    sc.blit(car, car_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    if yr < 490:
        if xr > 550:
            rotatex += yr / 515 + 1
        else:
            rotatex -= yr / 515 + 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    if yr > 550:
        if xr > 550:
            rotatex -= yr / 515 + 1
        else:
            rotatex += yr / 515 + 1
    if rotatex >= 360:
        rotatex = 0
    if(rotatex < 0):
        rotatex = 360 + rotatex 
    if xr < 490:
        x = x + V * math.cos(math.radians(270-rotatex))
        y = y + V * math.sin(math.radians(270-rotatex))
    if xr > 550:
        x = x - V * math.cos(math.radians(270-rotatex))
        y = y - V * math.sin(math.radians(270-rotatex))
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.event.pump()
pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I've tried to set timeout in `serial.Serial` 0, but it gives me an error:

> xr = int(ser.readline().decode('ascii').strip())
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Because it can't read data so fast.

Comment: if you set timeout 0, it doesn't wait for the characters to arrive. but default could be that 3 seconds. so set some useful timeout

Comment: This is not what causes 3s delays, but you use a 4800 baud rate. Your Arduino certainly could handle much faster communication.

Comment: For the baudrate, i will recommend to go to 115200.

Comment: @Tome, you now the timeout of read in python? 4800 baud comm doesn't take 3 seconds for 20 chars

Comment: @svtag I've tried. I still have this error.